# Libreoffice not displaying fonts properly (Ubuntu 22.04 XFCE)

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, fonts, xfce, pdf

I'm trying to edit a PDF on LibreOffice Draw and the fonts aren't displaying (or exporting) properly in it which makes editing it very difficult. Here's an image showing what I mean.

[image: Side by side comparison of Libreoffice Draw and a PDF reader.]

What do I do?

Comment: Can you use the command `pdffonts yourpdf.pdf` and add the output to the question?

Comment: It's not clear what is not displaying correctly, what are you expecting to see that is not in the image you shared? Also, useful to add the exact Ubuntu version (eg from `lsb_release -a`) , and exact LibreOffice version (eg from `apt-cache policy ...`). If you imported the pdf from another program, did the pdf embed the fonts?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that there are many fonts in use on other operating systems that have incompatible licenses, and aren't distributed by default. Try `apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer fonts-ubuntu*` as a start, `apt install font-manager` might be helpful, and `apt install fonts-*` as a last resort - if you're feeling reckless.

You can run `fc-list` to get a list of currently installed fonts; when I run `fc-list | wc -l` on kUbuntu 23.04, the result is `785`. Also try running `fc-cache -fv` to update font cache.

Comment: `apt install fonts-*` would install almost all font packages in the Ubuntu archive. It's very unlikely that a user wants to do that.